# Combine multiple values into one in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary having ids as key and value will be the ids to which it will be clubbed ( which is actually the ref data).

There is one more list which only contains the ids but for specific name.

First list have 100  different ids from 1 to 100.
I am checking whether the ids for specific name in list 2 is present in list 1.If they are present then saving those ids. But there is a special condition in it.

e.g. If ids present in list 2 have clubbed ids (which we are checking from the ref dictionary) then we have to save only the clubbed id
Let us suppose the ids in list 2 is 1,10,21. 1 and 10 are clubbed with 21.Therefore, I only have to save one id which is the clubbed one i.e. 21 but not to save 1 and 10. In this case we are saving only 1 instead of 3.

If these ids dont have any clubbed id then 3 ids will be saved (1,10,21).

---

Updated:

Dictionary have 1 to 100 ids and some of the ids  have clubbed ids and some dont

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
//Key is id and the value is clubbedid
dict.Add(1,"21");
dict.Add(10,"21");
dict.Add(21,"None"); 
// etc

//In the list 2 we have ids for specific name 
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
list2.Add(1);
list2.Add(10);
list2.Add(21);
```

First i will check whether all the three ids in list 2 are in reference dictionary.And then will assign the value in     other list of object in the field Id.

```
foreach(int value on list2)
{
    if(dict.ContainsKey(value))
    {
        List<class> list3 = new  List<class> list3();
        list3.Id = value;
    }
}
```

So I have added all the three ids 1,10,21 one by one in id field of list3. Now the list3 contains three ids. In the simple     case it is correct where none of the id have clubbed id.

But as you can see in my reference dictionary, ids 1 and 10 have clubbed id as 21.Therefore, in the list3 I have to store     only one value which is 21 (only clubbed id removing the other one 1 and 10)

Any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "clubbed" here...

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Are they seals?

Comment: *I have a dictionary having ids as key and value will be the ids to which it will be clubbed* so are you saying you have something like a `Dictionary<int,List<int>>`? *There is one more list which only contains the ids but for specific name.* This is a little confusing. Is it a `List<int>`? Then how is it connected to a "name"? Or is it a `List<Foo>` where `Foo` has `Id` and `Name` properties? Or did you mean that this is a dictionary too? A `Dictionary<string,int>` or maybe even `Dictionary<int,string>`?

Comment: *First list have 100 different ids from 1 to 100. I am checking whether the ids for specific name in list 2 is present in list 1* You said you had a dictionary and a list, now you have 2 lists? Where did the second list come from? Or are you interchangeably using dictionary and list? (please, don't do that)

Comment: Post a code sample with what you have & what you expect as an output.
I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: *If ids present in list 2 have clubbed ids (which we are checking from the ref dictionary) then we have to save only the clubbed id* So *I think* you are saying that you want to group the ids in list 2 if they appear in a list in your dictionary and save only the dictionary key? Is that anywhere close to right? And save where?

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippet.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated and code snippet is also added.

Comment: You've still not explained what "Clubbed" means.

Comment: Clubbed means simply that in this case ids are 1,10 and 21. Since 1 and 10 have clubbed ids as 21. So we will not save all the three ids in the list. We will instead club and save only 21.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it has no meaning whatsoever - you've just chosen a word and used it completely out of context (A club is typically a thing you hit someone with, or a suit in a standard deck of cards, or a group you belong to). Fine. no problem. Anyway - did you check my updated answer?

Comment: How much it will change for List of tuple instead of dictionary i. e List<Tuple<int,int>> instead of reference dictionary mentioned in the question.Item 1 will be id and Item 2 will be clubbed id?

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is not particularly clear - as per the comments currently.*

---

To have a stab at this - assuming `list1` is an `IEnumerable<int>` and `list2` is a `Dictionary<int,int[]>` then I think what you're trying to do is along the lines of the following

```
// numbers 1-100
var list1 = Enumerable.Range(1,100).ToList();

// 3 entries
var list2 = new Dictionary<int,int[]>(){
        {1,new[]{21}},
        {10,new[]{21}},
        {21,new int[0]}
};

var result = list2.SelectMany(item => {
   if(!list1.Contains(item.Key))
       return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
   if(item.Value != null && item.Value.Length>0)
      return item.Value;
   return new[]{item.Key};
}).Distinct();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/RZMEHU88506

---

Having updated your question, this might work for you:

```
 var list3 = list2.Select(x => {
    int value = 0;
    // if the dict contains the key and the value is an integer
    if(dict.ContainsKey(x) && int.TryParse(dict[x], out value))
        return value;
    return x;
})
.Distinct()
.Select(x => new MyClass(){ Value = x })
.ToList();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/KEEY8337

Comment: Any help will be appreciated and code snippet is also added.

Comment: @Ritesh next time use a code snippet that *actually compiles*! See updated answer.

Comment: How much it will change for List of tuple instead of dictionary i. e List<Tuple<int,int>> instead of reference dictionary mentioned in the question.Item 1 will be id and Item 2 will be clubbed id?

Comment: @Ritesh well it'll be slow for starters! Just turn the tuple into a dictionary `myTupleList.ToDictionary(k => k.Item1, v => v.Item2)`